# Adobe Flash Builder Video Player not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, video

I am trying to get a video player to play in my application...this is my whole application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       applicationComplete="init()"
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       creationComplete="myVid.play();">

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:VideoDisplay id="myVid" 
                        source="../assets/video.mp4"
                        height="250" 
                        width="250"
                        />
    </s:VGroup>

    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[ 
        private function init():void  
        { 
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE; 
        } 
        ]]> 
    </fx:Script> 
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

The video (video.mp4) is inside a folder I created called assets, how come this not appearing. I got this example from here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc78f87379113c38b-669905c51221a3b97af-8000.html

Under "Using the Spark VideoDisplay control"

**UPDATE**

I found this line of code, but I don't know where to apply it. `OSMFSettings.enableStageVideo = false` So confused.

Comment: Did you get this working?  I noticed that this is the same code as your other question...

Comment: May be your video codec is not support the player. Please check you video codec. Or try another video.